# How to set font for scientific numbers in logarithmic plots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, fonts

When setting the fonts via rcParams, e.g.

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['FreeSans', ]
```

The fonts do not change for logarithmic plots. Instead the stay at the default font type.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
for n in range(1, 10):
    ax1.plot(range(1, 10), arange(1, 10)**n, label='poly{}'.format(n))
    ax2.plot(range(1, 10), arange(1, 10)**n, label='poly{}'.format(n))
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax2.legend(ncol=2);
```

[image: lin-and-log-plot]

I am wondering if there's a way to set the scientific font type?

(One can see the different font when checking the "ones" in the two plots.)

Comment: there's a [bug report](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8017) on it. It seems to be determined by the mathtext default.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the mathtext fontset to 'custom' did the trick, for me:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['FreeSans', ]
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'custom'
```